# How do we output bash resource output in chef to a file?

Tags: ruby, bash, chef-infra

I have a bash script which has to be put into a Chef recipe. I expect to see the output of the bash code when I run it using `chef-client-z -o` recipe and also print it to some file. For example if I run `cat hello.txt` it should display the contents of the `hello.txt` file when i run `chef-client -z -o` recipe as well as print it to a file.

I have tried putting the code in a script but the output shows that the file does not have write permissions. I have no clue regarding how to print the contents of the `hello.txt` to the console.

```
results = "/tmp/output.txt"
file results do
    mode '0755'
    action :delete
end


cmd = "cat hello.txt"
bash 'Checking system-auth settings' do
  code <<-EOH
    #{cmd} &> #{results}
    EOH
end
ruby_block "Results" do
    only_if { ::File.exists?(results) }
    block do
        print "\n"
        File.open(results).each do |line|
            print line
        end
    end
end
```

The error output I receive is File `/tmp/output.txt` exists but is not writable so it cannot be deleted.

Comment: Your `file` resource can't delete the /tmp/output.txt, because it does not have permisisons. Try running chef-client with sudo.

Comment: It solved the issue. Thanks!